# How do I paint an InkResponse above other widgets?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a [`LeafRenderObjectWidget`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LeafRenderObjectWidget-class.html) in a `Column`:

```dart
Column(children: [CustomRenderObject(), InkResponse(child: ..), ...])
```

Below that, there is an `InkResponse`. Normally, the splash and highlight from the `InkResponse` would draw above the previous widget in the `Column`. If I had the following scenario, the highlight and splash would be rendered above the `Container`:

```dart
Column(children: [Container(height: ..), InkResponse(child: ..), ...])
```

However, in *my scenario* with the `RenderObject`, anything I draw **at the bottom** of my `CustomRenderObject` widget in the [`paint` method of my `RenderBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderObject/paint.html) will be drawn **above** the `InkResponse` splash and highlight.
The `Material` is a parent of the `Column`.

This means that my `InkReponse` highlight and splash are **cut off** at the top. I do not want to add additional padding to my `InkResponse`. How can I have my `InkResponse` draw above my `RenderBox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions to this problem are [described in the troubleshooting section of the `InkResponse` class](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html#the-ink-splashes-arent-visible).

If you are just using a simple **colored** `Container` or something similar, you can use the [`Ink` widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Ink-class.html) instead, which will paint onto the `Material` and thus render the `InkResponse`'s highlight and splash above.

Another solution would be adding a `Material` of type `MaterialType.transparency`:

```dart
Material(type: MaterialType.transparency, child: InkResponse(..))
```

This would go right below the `InkResponse` itself. However, this does not solve my problem as it clips the `InkResponse` into a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

The `InkResponse` will draw the splash above the parent widget in the tree and not in the siblings. That explains why it is painting in your `Material` widget that is above the `Column` because the `Column` itself is just a layout `MultiChildRenderObjectWidget`.

The solution that you provided, is actually a good approach that is used sometimes, but since you want to render the splash effect in your `LeafRenderObjectWidget`, and because it has not children, Flutter doesn't know where actually you want to render the splash effect. I'm afraid you can't use `InkResponse` to render splashes in a leaf widget.

An *ugly* solution that might work, can go from using a `Stack` to place each widget on the top of the other but you'd still have to make sure they would have the same appearance. If it is a complex render object, this can be tricky.